What would be done in a bathtub replacement?
I am replacing a bathtub in an existing remodel. Here is an existing picture of the bathtub.

From drywall to drywall, the measurement is 59". The tub itself is 30" deep. With the trim around it, it's is ~33" deep.
Here is the tub I am installing. Please see the highlighted trim.
.
From outer edge of trim to outer edge of trim, it is 59 5/8" x 32".
What I'm wondering is how will the installation be done, if I am wanting to put backsplash there?
The way I understand, first this tub will be removed. Behind the tub, there is no drywall, so 1/2" x 2 = 1" is added to the overall length there from stud to stud is 59" + 1" = 60", meaning the tub will fit. Since the space is so tight, will it be possible to put backsplash behind the tub, like this:

I am not sure if there is enough room left over for cement board and tile. Or is there another way to put the backsplash? What I am worried about is the new tub has small 1/8" grooves (see picture above) that are supposed to meet with the wall, so how will the tiles intersect with them if I don't put the tiles behind the tub? Also, how will the backsplash there be attached if I want to do it till the ceiling? Will I have to remove the existing drywall above the tub to make it an even surface and attach cement board?
I would love any comments/confirmation of how this will be done. Thank you all ahead of time!!!

The new tub is made to fit into a standard 60 inch opening between studs.
Here is the process for achieving the look you want:
Install the tub. Attaching to the studs per manufacturer's instructions.
Get it level. Install the drain and overflow.
Have your rough plumbing in place for the water, if you are changing from the old position.
The cement board is anchored to the studs. Starting at the bottom edge of the tub, have the panels overlap the tub flange. Use screws rasted for cement board.
Add the remaining cement board to the ceiling.
Tape and mud the seams using cement board rated mesh tape. (This doesn't have to be pretty, just fill in the gaps.)
This step is optional for a tub only set up, I would apply a waterproofing such as RedGuard or Aqua defense My personal preference is to apply it all the way to the ceiling. A minimum for just the tub is 36" above the tub edge.
Install your tile. Then grout and install any trim.

Gotcha. Thanks for the detailed answer. My main concern was I do not have to do any backsplash work prior to the removal of the old bathtub and install of the new bathtub, correct?

Removal of the old surround  is the first step. The tub/ surround combos are made to be placed right to the studs.  However one can never know exactly what others have done. Besides, nothing can be done until the old surround is removed.

Thanks a ton for your suggestions. My one other question is this. Do you think the new tub would be of significanlty more weight that it would require extra reinforcement of the joists?

I would have no way of knowing that.  Find the weight of the new tub and compare it to the weight of the old tub, or a tub very similar. Compare how much water both tubs hold and If the weight difference is minimal you have no problem.  Think of it this way. An average tub in an average home could be used by a 250 pound person, or a 120 pound person.

Gotcha. The new tub holds 55 gal, so 460 lb and weighs 115 lb. Including 160lb human, it'll be ~700-750lbs in total. So basically 850-900 lbs including backsplash. The old tub only held ~45 gal and weighed 150 so around 650 lbs including water and a person in the tub. Long story short, 650 vs 900 lbs. What do you think? The bathroom itself is 5' x 8' and has a toilet, 30" vanity with 2cm quartz, and the tub.

The backsplash is anchored to the walls, that are designed to hold such weight without an issue. That is unless the home is poorly constructed and not to normal construction methods and codes.  Your math is skewed also.  A 150 lb person will displace the same amount of water in each tub so that weight is a non factor. Using the weight of the tub and the weight of the water for both tubs and comparing, the difference is only about 50 pounds.  This should not be any worry, again unless your home is built very poorly.

If it makes you feel better and you have axcess to the space under the bath , you can add support. In normal circumstances it is not necessary.

Thanks a ton! Tub was just installed today, just as you instructed. Really appreciate the suggestions @RMDman

I'm glad it all coming together for you.

One question I did have... The tub was installed and it's not perfectly level. Can you take a look at this and tell me if it's too unlevel? I am afraid of pooling.

You should try to get that level. Some composite shims under the right side. Is the bottom supported?

Just finished getting it level with shims and it drains perfectly. The tub is really amazing, I really appreciate your insights!
